# "Mastermind" game in emu8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, game-development, x86-16, identifier, emu8086

I have a problem with my code. It always says it has double declaration of the code and I don't know how to fix it. Whether I merge segments or leave them like this it says the same thing. (also i don't really know much about this program. we are doing it at school so that's about it.)

Here's the code

```
; Mastermind game in assembly language for the 8086

; Declare data segment
data segment
    code db 4 dup (0) ; Random 4-digit code
    guess db 4 dup (0) ; Player's current guess
    feedback db 10 dup (0) ; Feedback for each attempt
    attempts db 0 ; Number of attempts
    digits db '0123456789', 0 ; Valid digits
data ends

; Declare code segment
code segment
start:
    ; Initialize the code
    call generate_code

    ; Loop for 10 attempts
    mov bx, 10
    repeat:
        ; Get the player's guess
        call get_guess

        ; Check the guess against the code
        call check_guess

        ; Give feedback to the player
        call give_feedback

        ; Check if the player won
        call check_win

        ; Decrement the number of attempts
        dec bx
        jnz repeat

    ; The player lost
    call print_lose
    jmp exit

; Generates a random 4-digit code
generate_code:
    ; Initialize the random number generator
    mov ax, 0
    mov cx, 0x1234
    mov dx, 0x5678
    call rand

    ; Generate 4 random digits
    mov cx, 4
    generate_digit:
        ; Get a random digit
        mov ax, 10
        call rand
        mov al, dl

        ; Store the digit in the code
        mov [code + cx - 1], al

        ; Decrement the counter
        dec cx
        jnz generate_digit

    ; Return
    ret

; Gets the player's guess
get_guess:
    ; Prompt the player
    call print_prompt
    call read_guess

    ; Validate the guess
    call validate_guess

    ; Return
    ret

; Reads the player's guess from the input
read_guess:
    ; Read 4 characters
    mov cx, 4
    read_character:
        ; Read a character
        call getchar

        ; Store the character in the guess
        mov [guess + cx - 1], al

        ; Decrement the counter
        dec cx
        jnz read_character

    ; Return
    ret

; Validates the player's guess
validate_guess:
    ; Check that each character is a valid digit
    mov cx, 4
    validate_character:
        ; Get the current character
        mov al, [guess + cx - 1]

        ; Check if the character is a valid digit
        mov bx, digits
        call strchr
        cmp ax, -1
        jz invalid

        ; Decrement the counter
        dec cx
        jnz validate_character

    ; Return
    ret
code ends
```

Comment: You should put your code between 3 back-quotes. After doing that (see my edit) it looks like 1 block of code...)

Comment: Also adding more info (using [edit]) to describe the details on "it always says it has double declaration of the code", can help getting better answers. When are you getting this message, and what are you doing to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

> it always says it has double declaration of the code

You are using the identifier *code* for two different things.
In `code db 4 dup (0)` it's the name of a **user-defined variable**, and in `code segment` it's the name of a **program segment**. In general, 'stuff' needs to be uniquely identified.
I suggest you choose another name for the variable like eg. *MyCode*.

### A further review

> ```
> mov [code + cx - 1], al
> mov [guess + cx - 1], al
> mov al, [guess + cx - 1]
> ```

In *generate_code*, *read_guess*, and *validate_guess* the instructions that use CX for an address component are invalid. On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) you can only use BX, SI, DI, and BP for addressing memory through registers.
I suggest you replace CX by SI in these loops:

```
generate_code:
    mov  ax, 0
    mov  cx, 0x1234
    mov  dx, 0x5678
    call rand
    mov  si, 4                       <<<
  generate_digit:
    mov  ax, 10
    call rand
    mov  al, dl
    mov  [MyCode + si - 1], al       <<<
    dec  si                          <<<
    jnz  generate_digit
    ret

read_guess:
    mov  si, 4                       <<<
  read_character:
    call getchar
    mov  [guess + si - 1], al        <<<
    dec  si                          <<<
    jnz  read_character
    ret

validate_guess:
    mov  si, 4                       <<<
  validate_character:
    mov  al, [guess + si - 1]        <<<
    mov  bx, digits                        ???
    call strchr
    cmp  ax, -1
    jz   invalid
    dec  si                          <<<
    jnz  validate_character
    ret
```

### A lurking problem

Your main program loop depends on the BX register as a counter. Yet one of the subroutines is modifying the value of BX for its own use. This will inevitably clash!
You could preserve the value of BX on the stack like in next example:

```
  mov  bx, 10
repeat:
  push bx               ; (1)
  call get_guess
  call check_guess
  call give_feedback
  call check_win
  pop  bx               ; (1)
  dec  bx
  jnz  repeat
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `loop` on 16-bit x86 doesn't have the performance issues associated with `loop` on modern x86, right?

Comment: @puppydrum64 On true 8086, `loop` is the better choice because of its smaller code size. However in the real address mode (also 16-bit) of the x86 in general, it is best to avoid this instruction.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that "real mode" was just an original 8086 that was also built into the machine, kind of like what Nintendo did with the Game Boy Advance (it had an ARM7TDMI to run Game Boy Advance games but essentially had a Game Boy Color CPU built into it as well.) Now *why* I thought that, I have no idea. Could have just been my imagination.